# NASM: operation size not specified

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm, x86-16

I wrote this code in emu8086 and it goes well in the emulator but when I'm trying to compile it with NASM it's throwing me up the error: "operation size not specified", help someone?

```
add bx,[3565]
sub bx,0xcc
mov [bx],0CCh
```

Comment: Surely NASM also told you which line of code the error was found on? `mov [bx],0CCh` needs a size specifier, e.g. `mov byte [bx],0CCh`. Also, `add bx,[3565]` looks weird. Why would you attempt to read from memory at offset 3565?

Answer (score 1):

NASM can't figure out what you meant by a line like `mov [bx],0CCh`. Clearly, 
this sets something to 0CCh. But do you want to have bx pointing to a single byte 
, short, long, ...? This will manifest itself as the fairly self-explanatory 
`error: operation size not specified` in NASM. You could avoid the error specifying the type, as shown below:

```
SECTION .text
    global start

start:
    add bx,[3565]
    sub bx,0xcc
    mov byte [bx],0CCh
```

That'd assemble it ok... of course, don't try to run it as it is, it'll produce `EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION`. Just open it with a debugger and you'll understand why.